# Lazyload image in the data-preview attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

currently i am implementing lazy load image by the following code , this code is from google .

```
<img class="lazy" src="placeholder-image.jpg" data-src="image-to-lazy-load-1x.jpg" data-srcset="image-to-lazy-load-1x.jpg 1x" alt="I'm an image!">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));

  if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
    let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          let lazyImage = entry.target;
          lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
          lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
          lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");
          lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
      });
    });

    lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
      lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
    });
  } else {
    // Possibly fall back to a more compatible method here
  }
});
```

now i need to implement this technique to `<li>` , this `<li>`
 come inside an slider .

```
 <li data-preview="sliders/my-image.jpg" data-ulr-link="#">  some html </li>
```

how i can apply lazy load for the image in `data-preview` attribute.

Comment: Are you asking how to apply the functionality to the `<li>` instead of an `<img>`?  Is this question about how to write the jquery selector?

Comment: This is what I am not sure about.  Try this and let me know if it is the solution that you are looking for: `querySelectorAll("li[data-preview='slidersmy-image.jpg']")`  But the truth is, I don't know if that is what you are trying to fix.

Comment: So are you asking for: `lazyImage.srcset = $("li[data-preview='slidersmy-image.jpg']").data('preview');` ?  Do you have multiple `li` tags like this?

Comment: The selector can be: `document.querySelectorAll("li[data-preview]")` then (I guess) the value can be grabbed like: `lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.data('preview');`

Comment: Please undelete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890465/create-php-function-for-tracking-the-url-parameter-once-present-then-save-the-pa if you want to post that question, and wait your turn to add a bounty to a post. The time limits are there for a reason.